# Rest API using Spring and MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-mvc

[image: my project structure][image]I've been developing a Rest API using `Spring` in which `MongoDB` is used for database.

Here is my code so far:

User.java:

```
@Id
private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

UserRepository interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>{

}
```

UserRestController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAll() {
        System.out.println("Get Method Invoked");
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
        return repo.save(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        repo.delete(id);
    }

}
```

ServletInitializer class:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("Initializer loaunched");
        return new Class[] { MongoSeparateServerConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cg.mongo")
public class MongoSeparateServerConfiguration {

}
```

That is all about the java classes and I run the `MongoDB` instance. When I try to start `tomcat` server, it gives an exception `BeanNotFoundException`.

How to fix this?

This is the exception I got:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cg.mongo.service.UserRepository com.cg.mongo.controller.UserRestController.repo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.cg.mongo.service.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It seems it cannot find a proper bean to autowire. Can you please write which bean it could not resolve, since I cannot see it on screenschot?

Comment: @NikolayTomitov i added the exception.It seems it is coming for the com.cg.mongo.service.UserRepository.Isn't it?

Comment: @SandunkaMihiran I fixed my answer you have to use EnableMongoRepositories and maven to have spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just Read Your Error Carefully. your answer is in your Exception stackTrace()

---

> **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException**: Error creating bean with name `userRestController: Injection of autowired dependencies failed`; nested exception is `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`: Could not autowire field: private `com.cg.mongo.service.UserRepository` `com.cg.mongo.controller.UserRestController.repo`; nested exception is `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`: No qualifying bean of type `[com.cg.mongo.service.UserRepository]` found for dependency: expected at           **least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire** candidate for this dependency.

**Not using Auto configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration and There is no @EnableMongoRepositories in your configuration class**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Auto configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration and there is no @EnableMongoRepositories in your configuration class so your repository not loaded in spring beans, I think you need to add @EnableMongoRepositories to your configuration class and set package name of repository, also User have to have @Document and @Id not the JPA one.
and be sure that your maven pom file have

```
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId> 
  </dependency>
```